# ionic 4 FCM not working or getting token , after build "ionic cordova build android --prod"

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

I using ionic 4 type=angular project

I am using FCM From Firebase for push notification ,

when i am using "ionic cordova build android" (debug mode) to build, FCM Push notification working fine ,

try to add flag --prod --release  The FCM not working; Ex: "ionic cordova build android --prod --release"

Any solution's plz

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: did you add google-services.json in project_folder/platforms/android/app?

Comment: yes i added the file google-services.json , everything working fine on normal build,  when try to get production build not notification coming , FCM no getting devices token

Comment: #peter_Haddad  error is FCM not getting a devices token when ionic production build

Answer (score 0):

This comment is not prod but it works

ionic cordova build android --aot --minifycss --minifyjs

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using pro-guard. I have encountered the same issue and added the following lines to proguard file to solve the issue.

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```